# Angular 6 what is the meaning of [(property)]

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6, In Prime NG  Module they have parameters like [(visible)]="displayAddDialog", I want to understand what is the menaing of "[(". I know that if we want to bind input we use [], for output we use (). But i am not aware of [()]. Please help me to understand, If possible give me an example

Comment: Hi, this is known as "two-way data binding". You can check documentation here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the "[()]" means both. The best example is when you use a ngModel.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) :

```html
<app-sizer [(size)]="fontSizePx"></app-sizer>
```

is equivalent to :

```html
<app-sizer [size]="fontSizePx" (sizeChange)="fontSizePx=$event"></app-sizer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This mean two binding in angular 2+ version

```
[(target)]="expression"
```

Binding types other than interpolation have a target name to the left of the equal sign, either surrounded by punctuation ([], ()) or preceded by a prefix (bind-, on-, bindon-).

The target name is the name of a property. It may look like the name of an attribute but it never is. To appreciate the difference, you must develop a new way to think about template HTML.

```
<input type=text [(ngModel)]="user.name" [value]="user.id"/>
```